# Como inserir uma linha na tabela sql ao clicar no botão?

Tags: php, sql, sql-insert

Tenho um site de imoveis que estou implementando a opção de favoritos. Quando abrir o imóvel e clicar em favorito, ele deverá inserir em uma nova linha na tabela favoritos, essa abaixo (status 1 é favorito), e se "desclicar" ele remove a linha:

```
id|idusuario|imovel|status
1 |   789   | 552  |  1
```

Minha dúvida é como fazer isso de forma dinâmica, realtime.
tenho as variaveis $idusuario e $idimovel.

Código PHP para inserir ou remover do favoritos, só não sei como chamar dinamicamente, sem abrir outra página:

```
$query = ("INSERT INTO favoritos (idusuario, imovel, status)
VALUES ('".$idusuario."', '".$idimovel."', '1'");
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: Usando `$.ajax()`, pode ser? Se puder posto um exemplo

Comment: Não entendi onde exatamente está a dificuldade. Já consegue enviar os dados para o servidor? Já tem a conexão com o banco de dados? O problema é construir o código SQL de INSERT ou mais que isso?

Comment: @WeesSmith pode sim, não tenho muito conhecimento no ajax

Comment: @bfavaretto não sei como fazer direito, sei que pode ser com ajax, mas não sei usar bem o ajax, os que fiz deu errado, só sei fazer se tipo clicar e abrir uma outra página para rodar a instrução para inserir uma nova linha

Comment: O que é exatamente `desclicar` ?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo seria um click para reverter uma ação já feita por outro click

Comment: Se fosse um `input type="checkbox` ou dois `input type="radio"` acho que seria melhor do que um botão que pode confundir se foi clicado ou desclicado.

Comment: `checkbox` marcado > status=1 desmarcado > status = 0. Com `radio` um pra status 1 e outro para status 0

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo vc ja tem o php que faz essas alterações?

Comment: Mas também existe a possibilidade de mudar o label do botão

Comment: São só idéias para o amigo Wees Smith considerar na resposta prometida

Comment: @WeesSmith tenho o php, acho que o que o Leo Cracciolo é uma boa, um checkbox, editei a resposta com o php que tenho criado

Comment: Quando for remover o favorito, é pra apagar a linha ou alterar o status?

Comment: é pra apagar a linha, isso, certo? $query=("DELETE FROM favoritos
WHERE idusuario = ".$idusuario." AND imovel = ".$idimovel) ;

Answer (score 3):

O `$.ajax()`:

```
$('#ID_DO_BOTAO').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"SEU_ARQUIVO.php",
        dataType:"Json",
        data:{'favorito':'favorito'},
        success:function(a){
            //retorno do php, ou um reload da pagina/elemento
        }
    });
});
```

SEU_ARQUIVO.php

```
if(($_POST['favorito'])&&($_POST['favorito']=='favorito')){
    //primeiro vc executa uma verificação se o usuário ja clicou ("SELECT * FROM favoritos WHERE idusuario = '$idusuario');
    if(usuario ja clicou){
        $query=("DELETE FROM favoritos WHERE idusuario = ".$idusuario." AND imovel = ".$idimovel);
    }else{
        $query = ("INSERT INTO favoritos (idusuario, imovel, status)
        VALUES ('".$idusuario."', '".$idimovel."', '1'");
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: legal, vou testar aqui

Comment: uma dúvida, o $idusuario e $imovel estão no arquivo onde vou iserir o ajax certo? não entendi como que eu passo eles para o favorito.php

Comment: faz essa chamada com essa logica que mandei direto nesse `favorito.php` então, fica mais facil pra vc eu acredito

Comment: eu fiz igual vc mandou (só removi o if para testar primeiro) mas não aconteceu nada. no arquivo onde coloquei $.ajax tem o $idusuario e $idimovel, o favorito.php pega esses valores sozinho?

Comment: Esses valores são definidos no favorito.php não?

Comment: não eles já estão na página: imovel.php tem as variaveis $idusuario e $idimovel. Aí nela eu coloquei o ajax e criei um outro arquivo favorito.php (que é o php que vc passou) ou fiz tudo errado?..rs

Comment: vc precisa passar esses valores pra outra pagina então, usando sessão da certo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77646/discussion-between-wees-smith-and-leandro-marzullo).